# Import ES6 module into global scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

**TLDR**: How can I make a module (imported via ES6 syntax) globally scoped (or reference an imported class inside another class)?

---

I'm importing a module from a package which wasn't implemented properly (no export etc) but am running into some issues.

What I am doing is using `var` to set the module to global (not great) e.g.

```
var Example = require('./node_modules/example/long_path_to_file.js');
```

As I need to use it like so in my class (the module takes control of `this` and class instances aren't available in the global scope so I can't use my class as I normally would):

```
new window.Example(...)
```

This works but it isn't great as I'm using webpack and would prefer to use the proper es6 syntax

```
import Example from './example';
```

and then in `example.js`

```
export default Example = require('./node_modules/example/long_path_to_file.js');
```

However this means it is no longer global scoped, and I'm unable to find a fix.

I've tried things like `window.Example = Example` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just to get this straight, `example/long_path_to_file.js` is setting a variable `window.Example` which you want to use via webpack?

Comment: `window.aaa = require(....)`\

Comment: @RGraham That file just exports some code I need to use; I was setting it to `window.Example` by using `var Example` in the outermost scope (not sure if `strict` mode even allows that). I need it to be global because this module takes over the context in my class (and es6 class instances aren't referenced in the global scope)

Comment: Then @RoyiNamir is correct

Comment: @RGraham my first example (using `require`) already works but I want to know how to make a module global using ES6

Comment: have you tried webpack.library settings?

Comment: @The I'm really new to Webpack and not sure what kind of option would help put this in the global scope, any ideas?

Comment: @user32394023 Are you using `webpack-dev-server` by any chance?

Comment: @user32394023 look at my answer

Comment: @RGraham I don't believe so, just standard webpack with a basic entry-output section and a module-loading section with babel/es2015.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using `webpack` it's easy to setup it. So here is a simple example how to implement it.

***webpack.config.js***

```
module.exports = {
  entry: 'test.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: 'home',
    library: 'home' // it assigns this module to the global (window) object
  }
  ...
}
```

***some.html***

```
<script>console.log(home)</script>
```

Also if you open your `bundle.js` file you will see how webpack did it for you.

```
var home =  // main point
/*****/ (function(modules) blablabla)
...
```

Also i suggest look at [***webpack library***](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) configuration.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, this is interesting, but the output file is my module, not the small module I am including and want to make global (say `bundle.js` is my module, but I want to `other.js` global which is at the top of `bundle.js` via `import`)

Comment: @user32394023 you can access to it like `home.mySmallModule`

Answer (score 7):

I've done some testing and this works correctly:

```
import './middleman';

// './middleman.js'
window.Example = require('./example.js').default
// OR
window.Example = require('./example.js').Example

// './example.js'
export function Example() {
  this.name = 'Example'
}
export { Example as default }
```