# webpack export function globally

Tags: reactjs, function, webpack

I'm new to using Webpack. 
I'm trying to access the function testResults() from my bundle.js.

**I'm getting the following error(s) in browser console:**

> Uncaught TypeError: myNewLibrary.testResults is not a function

**Inside my terminal:**

```
storecheck-react |Hash: 5aa3626e36e217209e16   storecheck-react | Version: webpack 3.8.1
storecheck-react | Time: 2523ms
storecheck-react |      Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
storecheck-react |  bundle.js   286 kB    0, 1  [emitted]  [big]  app:
storecheck-react | bundle.css  2.98 kB    0, 1  [emitted]         app:
storecheck-react |   [49] ./js/showResults.js 159 bytes {0} {1} [built]
storecheck-react |     + 189 hidden modules
storecheck-react |
storecheck-react | ERROR in chunk showResults [entry]
storecheck-react | bundle.js
storecheck-react | Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename bundle.js
```

**file structure**

```
-- src
---- css/
---- js/
---- ** showResults.js
---- app.js (requires './js/showResults')
```

**showResults function**

```
export function testResults(){
  return 'hello' // just for testing if I can access global function.
}
```

**Webpack**
I've searched on Google for making a function globally and there were some tips adding 'Library' to the webpack config.
My entry and output in my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
entry: {
    'app:':'./app.js',
    'showResults':'./js/showResults.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js', // bundle.js
     library: 'myNewLibrary',
  },
```

**Call to function in an external page:**

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/static/bundle.js"></script>

<script>
var result = myNewLibrary.testResults();
console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: at least you can do the next `window.amazingFunction = () => {...}`

Comment: @TheReason I'd like to know how this fix this in webpack.. if possible.

Comment: i believe you should use `export default` instead of `named export` - [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600751/import-es6-module-into-global-scope)

Comment: It's worth specifying what version of webpack you're using as the loader configs can vary. I would suggest taking a look at the expose loader, just note this link is for version 3 specifically: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Answer (score 0):

In *app.js* re-export the function in the following manner:

```
export { testResults } from './js/showResults';
```