# What is the global function or namespace for ES6 modules after they are compiled with babel-preset-es2015

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, compilation, babeljs

I've got dev tools open and I'm trying to find the installed modules using the console. Below are versions from my `package.json`. The compiled bundle.js can be found at https://pastebin.com/EbTg6bSF.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@material/button": "^0.40.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly: There is none.

1. Individual modules are (by default) not exposed to global scope. The whole point of bundling modules is to create a self contained piece of code.
2. Dev dependencies are usually not imported by production code but
   used by server scripts to create a bundle, do linting, etc. They are usually not loaded in the browser and
   wouldn't be included in the bundle anyway.

If that doesn't clear your concerns, please provide more information.

Comment: I am running the bundled code on a local machine. My understanding is that when ES6 modules are "compiled", they are made compatible with ES5. I had hoped this meant there would be something in the global scope to allow me to see them as a simple object or something like that.

Comment: You can configure webpack to do that. See [Import ES6 module into global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35600751/218196)

Comment: I've tried some combinations of webpack [output options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library) and [babel options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options) to no avail. While a global var is created, it is always an empty object. I'm going to treat this as undoable, or at least inadvisable, although I may have overlooked something. Just sharing my results.