# Vue import shorthand or one line statement

Tags: javascript

Good Day!

Would like to ask if there's a short hand for this code or one line statement.

```
import axiosHelper from'./mixin/AxiosAlertHelper.js'
window.axiosMix = axiosHelper;
```

Comment: You should be careful about the tags you use, this is only javascript related... I would drop all other tags.

Comment: @GiladBar I am sorry, i am currently working a small app using vue, anyway just drop the other tags. sorry again

Comment: Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600751/import-es6-module-into-global-scope), it suggests solutions to a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `require` statement.

windows.yourFieldName = require('lib_name').method;